# Getting unsigned int from json object in java

Tags: java, database, database-design, types

How can i get unsigned int number in java from json object. It truncates the value since its not supported. Is there anyway to get it or should i just go for long??

```
data.getInt("some key");
```

Here `data` is the json object.
I have the field as `unsigned integer` in the database.

Comment: I'd go for Long immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i=data.getInt("some key");


long j=0x00000000ffffffffL&i;
```

j is what you need;The problem is it is negative ,when the highest bit of int is 1.For example,0xffffffff is -1;0x0ffffffff is positive,but it is out of range of int.You can extend it to long and set hight 32 bit all to 0.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: add some explaination